# JSLint Validation error "combine this with the previous var statement"

Tags: javascript

JSLint Validation error "combine this with the previous var statement"

How do I combine this so I don't get JSLint Validation error? I get the validation error on the lines of code in getClassName function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
'use strict';
// This function is used to calculate the date
function dateString(dateToDisplay) {

    var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
        'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        dayNames = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
            'Friday', 'Saturday'];

// Use current date if no parameter or bad date provided
    if (dateToDisplay === undefined || !(dateToDisplay instanceof Date)) {
        dateToDisplay = new Date();
    }

    return dayNames[dateToDisplay.getDay()] + ', ' // Day of week: Sunday
        + monthNames[dateToDisplay.getMonth()] + ' ' // Name of month: July
        + dateToDisplay.getDate() + ', ' // Day of month: 20
        + dateToDisplay.getFullYear(); // Year: 1969
}


$('#safetyRecord').hide(); // hides the header with the id of safetyRecord until we are ready to display it later in the code
$('#today').text(dateString()); // changes the text in the span with the id of today to the current date using the dateString function
function getClassName(days) { // this function determines  which css style to apply to the id daysSinceLastAccident and the id message based on the number of days since last accident
    if (days >= 730) { return "great"; }
    if (days >= 180) { return "good"; }
    if (days >= 60) { return "marginal"; }
    if (days >= 14) { return "poor"; }
    if (days >= 0) { return "disaster"; }
}

$('#checkRecord').click(function () { // when the checkRecord button is clicked the number of days since last accident is calculated, storing the number in a variable.
    var userEnteredDate = new Date($('#dateOfLastAccident').val()); // variable that stores user entered date
    var today = new Date(); 
    var minutes = 1000 * 60; // calculation used to convert miliseconds to minutes
    var hours = minutes * 60; // calculation used to conver minutes into hours
    var days = hours * 24; // calculation used to convert hours to days
    var years = days * 365; // calculation used to convert days into years
    var daysSinceAccident = Math.floor((today.getTime() - userEnteredDate.getTime()) / days); // calculation used to find the difference between current date and user entered date as a whole number
    var className = getClassName(daysSinceAccident); // variable clasName finds the correct css style to apply based on daysSinceAccident
    $('#daysSinceLastAccident').text(daysSinceAccident); // replaces the content of the element with id daysSinceLastAccident with the number of days accident-free
    $('#daysSinceLastAccident').removeClass();
    $('#daysSinceLastAccident').addClass(className); // applies css class style to element with id daysSinceLastAccident

    $('#safetyRecord').show(); // Using the same timeframes, a custom message styled with the appropriate css class in the paragraph with id message is displayed.
    $('#message').removeClass(); 
    $('#message').addClass(className);
    $('#message').html(className + " is the current safety record.");
});
```

});

Comment: Is this the entire code? Whats this prev var statement.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This error means that you have multiple `var` statements in some of your functions, such as:

```
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
```

JSLint wants you to combine the variable declarations in a single `var` statement like:

```
var x = 1,
    y = 2;
```

Comment: I figured it out. For some reason the JSLint Validation error was showing that the error was in the getClassName function but really it was the variables in the .click function. It makes sense now, I was thrown off by JSLint validation directing me to the wrong line of code.

Answer (score 4):

I think JSLint is referring to these few lines of your code (towards the bottom of the code you have provided):

```
var userEnteredDate = new Date($('#dateOfLastAccident').val()); // variable that stores user entered date
var today = new Date(); 
var minutes = 1000 * 60; // calculation used to convert miliseconds to minutes
var hours = minutes * 60; // calculation used to conver minutes into hours
var days = hours * 24; // calculation used to convert hours to days
var years = days * 365; // calculation used to convert days into years
var daysSinceAccident = Math.floor((today.getTime() - userEnteredDate.getTime()) / days); // calculation used to find the difference between current date and user entered date as a whole number
var className = getClassName(daysSinceAccident); // variable clasName finds the correct css style to apply based on daysSinceAccident
```

You can avoid declaring them multiple times by delimiting each variable with a comma:

```
var userEnteredDate = new Date($('#dateOfLastAccident').val()),
    today = new Date(),
    minutes = 1000 * 60,
    hours = minutes * 60,
    days = hours * 24,
    years = days * 36,
    daysSinceAccident = Math.floor((today.getTime() - userEnteredDate.getTime()) / days),
    className = getClassName(daysSinceAccident);
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly it. I was thrown off by the JSLint error pointing to the lines of code in the getClassName function. Thankyou